# Can clang's libFuzzer test more than 1 API in the same binary?

Tags: c++, clang++, fuzzing, fuzz-testing, libfuzzer

[libFuzzer's documentation](https://llvm.org/docs/LibFuzzer.html) gives an example of how you would fuzz an API:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

extern "C" int LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const uint8_t *data, size_t size) {
  if (size > 0 && data[0] == 'H')
    if (size > 1 && data[1] == 'I')
       if (size > 2 && data[2] == '!')
       __builtin_trap();
  return 0;
}
```

I have APIs that take in single instances of different c++ types.
I test the following way:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include "my_api.hh"

extern "C" int LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const uint8_t *data, size_t size) {
  auto t = safe_deserialize<MyType>(data,size);
  my_api(t); 
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is, if I want to test 10 APIs, I'm left creating 10 separate binaries.  I would like a single binary that is more akin to a set of unit tests.  Something like this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include "my_api.hh"

extern "C" int LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const uint8_t *data, size_t size) {
  auto t = safe_deserialize<MyType_1>(data,size);
  my_api_1(t); 
  return 0;
}

extern "C" int LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const uint8_t *data, size_t size) {
  auto t = safe_deserialize<MyType_2>(data,size);
  my_api_2(t); 
  return 0;
}

extern "C" int LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const uint8_t *data, size_t size) {
  auto t = safe_deserialize<MyType_3>(data,size);
  my_api_3(t); 
  return 0;
}
```

This doesn't work because you can't have duplicate instances of `LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput`.
Is there a way to use Clang's libFuzzer tooling, to test more than 1 API in the same binary?

I suppose I could create some kind of universal function that dispatches to all of the other APIs, but that's undesirable because then I would need to build a corpus that is really a collection of unrelated corpuses, and crash results will be mixed across various APIs.

Comment: any suggestions on implementing your discussed issue?

Comment: @KeithApe I just create a program for every API I want to fuzz.  Generally, we can just choose some high level functions and that will get the rest of the code reached.

Answer (score 1):

How about it? You can try this. Not sure, it will work or not.

```
extern "C" int LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const uint8_t *data, size_t size) {
      auto t1 = safe_deserialize<MyType_1>(data,size);
      auto t3 = safe_deserialize<MyType_2>(data,size);
      auto t3 = safe_deserialize<MyType_3>(data,size);

      my_api_1(t1); 
      my_api_2(t2); 
      my_api_3(t3); 
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Well I feel silly for not thinking of this. Yup, worked for me. I had to wrap each statement with an exception catch but otherwise worked fine.